# How to output comma-separated strings using bash brace expansion

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like

```
$ echo a{b,c,d}
```

to output a comma-separated list like

```
ab,ac,ad
```

instead of the usual output

```
ab ac ad
```

What's the easiest way to do that on the command line?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming that the *elements* do not contain spaces, you could translate spaces to commas:

```
echo a{b,c,d} | tr ' ' ,
```

which produces:

```
ab,ac,ad
```

You can also use ranges with characters:

```
echo a{b..d} | tr ' ' ,
```

This is especially useful if you want a larger range.

Answer (score 18):

It seems bash does not use $IFS to join the generated words. Another technique would be to store the generated words in an array and then $IFS *will* be in play:

I'm going to use a subshell so I don't alter this shell's IFS: pick one of

```
( words=( a{b,c,d} ); IFS=,; echo "${words[*]}" )
( set -- a{b,c,d}; IFS=,; echo "$*" )
```

That emits the comma-separates string to stdout. If you want to capture it:

```
joined=$( set -- a{b,c,d}; IFS=,; echo "$*" )
```

Comment: It does *not* join the generated words at all. That's the whole point, it expands to separate words.

Answer (score 6):

I am sure there are many ways to accomplish this.  Here is one method:

```
echo a{b,c,d} | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

Comment: sed alternative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871534/concatenate-in-bash-the-output-of-two-commands-without-newline-character

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bash-only solution.

```
(IN=$(echo a{b,c,d}); echo ${IN// /,})
# ab,ac,ad
```

The part before the semicolon assigns `ab ac ad` to the variable `IN` and the second part uses search and replace to change all spaces to commas. The `//` means all matches, not just the first.

Do it all in a subshell (the enclosing parentheses) to not pollute your namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Expand the elements like you showed and then loop over them, adding the comma to all but the first iteration:

```
for i in a{b,c,d}; do
  u="${u:+$u, }$i"
done
echo "$u"
```

Result:

```
ab, ac, ad
```

See [bash parameter substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that in many contexts, a trailing comma is acceptable in such a list.  **IF** a trailing comma is acceptable, the easiest way to handle the substitution is `printf`:

```
some-command "$(printf %s, a{b,c,d} )"
```

(Where `some-command` is a command that runs on a comma separated list, and doesn't care about a trailing comma.)

Actually, even if you must not have a trailing comma you can use `printf`; you just need to specify the number of arguments you expect, which makes it clumsier for very long lists:

```
some-command "$(printf %s,%s,%s a{b,c,d} )"
```