# MySQL Select with function IN () with bash array

Tags: shell-script, mysql, array, sql

How can I do this with an array? (without storing the array as regular variable)

```
VAR='String1 String2 String3'
SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE xy IN ( ${VAR// /, } );
```

not working example:

```
SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE xy IN ( ${ARRAY[@]// /, } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array expansion & replacement *is* working, but there are no spaces in your array *elements*. Compare with:

```
$ array=("one two" three four)
$ echo "${array[@]/ /, }"
one, two three four
```

You're trying to re-join the array elements with a comma & space (`,`) between them. I'll <strike>steal</strike>copy [one of glenn jackman's answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121660/117549) in this vein:

```
$ array=(String1 String2 String3)
$ joined=$( set -- "${array[@]}"; IFS=,; echo "$*" )
```

Then you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE xy IN "$joined"
```

As an example:

```
$ array=("String1 String2" String3 String4)
$ joined=$( set -- "${array[@]}"; IFS=,; echo "$*" )
$ echo "$joined"
String1 String2,String3,String4
```

I don't know off-hand what you'll need to do to the SQL to quote array elements (Strings) that contain spaces (if any).